# How to implement a median split of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to return an ArrayList of values above the median of a column. For example I have a list of objects like:

```
List<ObjectX> where 
Object X has a value v such that v=25.
Object X has a value v such that v=15.
Object X has a value v such that v=5.
Object X has a value v such that v=35.
```

My attempt:

```
public static ArrayList<ObjectX> medianSplit(ArrayList<ObjectX> data,boolean lowerHaf){
    Collections.sort(data);
     return data.subset(0,data.size()/2);
}
```

This is not a school project, and I able to use any code, my attempt was based off another SO post.

Comment: What column?  All I see is a row.

Comment: What was the result? What is not working for you? What debugging have you done?

Comment: What is the boolean being used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work using [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(2);
    list.add(232);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(89);
    list.add(77);
    list.add(12);
    list.add(19);

    List<Integer> lowerHalf = medianSplit(list);

    System.out.println("list: " + lowerHalf);
}

public static List<Integer> medianSplit(List<Integer> data) {
    Collections.sort(data);
    return data.subList(0, data.size() / 2);
}
```

Output:

```
list: [2, 4, 12]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sublist with subList(0,N), N is exclusive.

This does not copy the items to a new list but it returns a list view over the existing list.

This should fix it:

```
data.subList(0, data.size() / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sort with java 8

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.v));
```

then you can return

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, data.size()/2);
```